# How to read and edit SQL views in C #

Tags: c#, sql

How to read and edit SQL view scripts in C #?

Or sqlserver in the system table storage view of the name and the corresponding view script, like sys.views this?

add:
In addition to through the sys.sp_helptext, C # have the corresponding method?

English comparison dishes, please forgive me.

Comment: I don't think we can edit SQL view scripts. Can you please elaborate the reason why do you want to edit view in C#?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: Can I ask why you need to edit view scripts? You want to create some kind of parser? Or just want to use this view in your c# code? In first scrnario you can use stringreader to open script and modify it line by line. In second, well, that depends :)

Comment: The requirement is that you need to be able to read and edit the saved sql view in the webpage.@KalyanBasa

Comment: Want to read and edit save sql view in webpage.Just found in sqlserver can use sys.sp_helptext to read the view script.@ArkadiuszRaszeja

Comment: So you are using something like MVC or MVVM and you want to fullfill your table by specyfic column "style". Is that you want to achieve? Are you using some kind of ORM? If yes you can just prepare list of rows in your controller or use MVVM :)

Answer (score 2):

The programmatic way to generate scripts from a SQL Server database is contained within the SQL Management Objects (SMO).

There is a [`Scripter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class that will allow you to generate scripts for any objects, and allows you to specify the same options that are provided when scripting through SSMS.

SMO is usually installed with SQL Server and are also [available to redistribute](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676).

To apply changes back into the database, you merely need to run the script (or an edited version of it) using any normal SQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

I use the sql script to handle it

SELECT * FROM sys.views

EXEC sys.sp_helptext @objname='viewname'

SELECT * FROM  syscomments